# WebFlux: Controller Doesn't Send to ServerHttpResponse

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm trying to code a proxy-controller with WebFlux 5.3.25:

```
@GetMapping(path = { "/proxy", "/proxy.*" }, params = "mode")
public Mono<Void> proxyWithMode(@RequestParam URI uri, @RequestParam String mode,
        @RequestAttribute ProxyService proxyService, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
  return WebClient.builder()
      .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)))
      .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, webConfiguration.getUserAgent())
      .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*" + "/*")
      .build()
      .get()
      .uri(uri)
      .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
        serverHttpResponse.getCookies().putAll(clientResponse.cookies());
        serverHttpResponse.getHeaders().putAll(clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders());
        Mono<String> content;
        switch (mode) {
          case "m3u8":
            content = clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(contentL -> playlistProvider.print(
                    playlistProvider.proxify(uri, proxyService,
                        playlistProvider.parse(contentL))));
            break;
          default: return serverHttpResponse.writeWith(clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class));
        }
        return content
            .map(contentL -> serverHttpResponse.bufferFactory().wrap(contentL.getBytes()))
            //.flatMap(dataBuffer -> serverHttpResponse.writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer)))
            .transform(dataBuffer -> serverHttpResponse.writeWith(dataBuffer))
            ;
      })
      .onErrorComplete(e -> {
        System.err.println("mode oec!");
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return true;
      });
}
```

If I remove the `case` and only leave the `default`, it runs fine, the `clientResponse` is written to `serverHttpResponse` and it all looks fine in the browser.

However, with the `case` in place it only writes the HTTP-headers, but not the content. I tried with `flatMap()` and `transform()` and the result is the same: In the developer console of the browser the header is there, but the "Preview"- and "Response"-tab only show "Failed to load response data". It looks as if the content is held back somewhere.

I don't know how far off I'm here, but can someone please add the missing piece here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I simply forgot to modify the content length of the response as I'm modifying it. So below the `switch()` it's now:

```
      return content
          .map(contentL -> {
            byte[] bytes = contentL.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            serverHttpResponse.getHeaders().setContentLength(bytes.length);
            return serverHttpResponse.bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
          })
          .transform(dataBuffer -> serverHttpResponse.writeWith(dataBuffer));
```